# How to make cross application ajax call hosted in same domain

Tags: ajax, jquery, cross-domain

I need to make an ajax call from one application(my-app) to other application(my-web) in the same domain. The ajax call will invoke the controller in my-web.

I made a ajax call like below, but got an error saying
"Ajax call ended in error"

code:

```
 var base = document.URL;   
 var servletContextPath = base.substr(0, base.indexOf(window.location.pathname))     + "/my-web";   
$(document).on("click", ":focus", function () {    
    $.ajax(servletContextPath + "/ajax/mycall");        
});
```

Both applications are hosted in weblogic like

```
 http://localhost:8090/my-web

 http://localhost:8090/my-app
```

What is the best possible way to do ajax call between applications?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a relative URL when making an AJAX call.

```
$(document).on("click", function () {    
    $.ajax("/my-web/ajax/mycall");        
});
```